# Nhibernate self reference performance

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

I have a model that looks like this:

```
public class ComponentAttributeDto
{
    public virtual long ComponentAttributeId { get; set; }
    public virtual ComponentAttributeDto ParentComponentAttributeDto { get; set; }
    public virtual string ComponentAttributeName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Value { get; set; }
    public virtual DataType DataType { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<ComponentAttributeDto> ChildComponentAttributes { get; set; }
}
```

With a mapping file of:

```
public class ComponentAttributeMapping : ClassMap<ComponentAttributeDto>
{
    public ComponentAttributeMapping()
    {
        Table("ComponentAttributes");

        Id(x => x.ComponentAttributeId)
            .GeneratedBy.Identity();

        References(x => x.ParentComponentAttributeDto)
            .Column("ParentComponentAttributeId");

        HasMany(x => x.ChildComponentAttributes)
            .Fetch.Select()
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
            .KeyColumn("ParentComponentAttributeId");

        Map(x => x.ComponentAttributeName)
            .Length(50);

        Map(x => x.Value)
            .Length(1500);

        Map(x => x.DataType)
            .Length(20);
    }
}
```

When loading this with a large dataset that goes about 4 levels deep the performance is terrible. When running profiler I noticed that is it executing a select statement for every single value in the table for the data I want to lookup. Is there a way I can improve the performance to do some type of join on the table or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You could use batch-size to pre-fetch instances, which reduces the number of queries     considerably.

mapping (not sure if it is supported by Fluent in the meanwhile):

```
HasMany(x => x.ChildComponentAttributes)
            .Fetch.Select()
            .SetAttribute("batch-size", "20")
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
            .KeyColumn("ParentComponentAttributeId");
```

If you had a Root property, you could make a query for the whole tree at once.

```
public class ComponentAttributeDto
{
  public virtual ComponentAttributeDto ParentComponentAttributeDto { get; private set; }
  public virtual ComponentAttributeDto Root 
  { 
     get 
     {
       if (ParentComponentAttributeDto == null) 
       {
         return this;
       }
       else 
       {
         return ParentComponentAttributeDto.Root;
       }
     }
     private set
     { /* just for NH to call it */ }
  }
  // ....
}
```

HasMany(x => x.Children).AsSet().SetAttribute("batch-size", "20")

the query

```
session.CreateQuery(
@"from ComponentAttributeDto
where Root = :root"
  .SetEntity(root);
```

should actually result in only a single query. Not sure if NH doesn't actually perform queries for the lists (ChildComponentAttributes), but it is worth a try.

Comment: Can you give an example of how adding a Root property would allow you to do that? I'm curious. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the entire data structure all at once? Usually when I run into this problem I just take away the mapping handling from nHibernate and deal with it myself. Create a method for the class called getChildren() and have it run the query when called. If you want to add a child record then add another method called addChild() and have it instantiate with it's own parent ID.

Answer (score 0):

You could eagerly fetch the hierarchy when you query. You can do this by using the eager fetch option in your query:

```
Session.QueryOver<ComponentAttributeDto>
       .Fetch(a => a.ChildComponentAttributes).Eager
```

Down to the level you want to fetch.